# How to roll up multiple rows filtered by a column value into a single row in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model for Notification:

```py
class Notification(models.Model):
    class VerbChoices(models.TextChoices):
        COMMENTED = 'commented'
        LIKE = 'like'

    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, default=generate_id, max_length=255)
    actor = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='notify_actions', null=True)
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='notifications')
    verb = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=VerbChoices.choices)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    target_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    target_object_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    target = GenericForeignKey('target_content_type', 'target_object_id')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I am trying to write a query which will return the count of rows with `verb` = LIKE, grouped by `target_object_id`. All the other rows should be without group by.

An example of the expected response:

```
 [
        {
            "id": "lokv7s1ljjarp9",
            "actor": {},
            "recipient": {},
            "verb": "commented",
            "read": true,
            "target": {
                "id": "5cj9kxbih6tbl7",
            },
            
        },
        {
            "id": "kaevq7mrsbvx4f",
            "actor": {},
            "recipient": {},
            "verb": "commented",
            "read": true,
            "target": {
                "id": "5cj9kxbih6tbl7",
                },
        },
        {
            "id": "jhoonpbu8m5p43",
            "actor": {<id of the first actor in the list>},
            "recipient": {},
            "verb": "liked",
            "read": "true if one of the records is unread",
            "target": {
                "id": "5cj9kxbih6tbl7",
                },
            "count": "total number of likes"
        }
]
```

Notice different responses for comments on the same target, and the likes are in a single response.

Comment: Can you share an example output you are looking for? You could do something like `Notification.objects.filter(verb="LIKE").values("target_object_id").annotate(likes=Count("pk"))` for example, if you just need the output for the verb `LIKE` only

Comment: I have updated the question with a sample response @BrianDestura. Let me know If any other details is missing.

Comment: This model looks strange. It seems to be storing data both for the **action** (e.g. someone liked a comment) and for the **notification** about an action. Shouldn't you have an `Action` model that stores information about the action, and just store a foreign key to it in the `Notification` model? If 1000 users need to be notified that a user liked a comment, do you store the same `actor`, `verb`, `target*` etc. 100 times?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this option

Notifications.objects.all().annotate(target_objects=Count('authors'))